# Ajax jsonp data to an array using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have created an jsonp request that retrieves data. The only problem is I cant seem to get the data in a array outside my loop:(

```
var lookbook_data = new Array();
$.ajax({
  url: "http://lookbook.king-quinna.nl/api/get_recent_posts/?callback=1&custom_fields=image1",
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function(data) {
for(var i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    lookbook_data[i] = data.posts[i].custom_fields.image1[0];      
}
}
});
console.log(lookbook_data);
```

So when I console.log they array inside the look it output the data the way it should. However outside the function it does not. But I did decleare the variable outside so I really dont get why:(

Btw Sorry for messy codebock cant seem to get it right with 4 spaces:(

Answer (score 2):

That ajax call is asynchronous, so you immediatly reach the last line of your code before it can finish.

You could make is synchronous (not recommended) with

```
async = 'false'
```

within the ajax call

or do something like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://lookbook.king-quinna.nl/api/get_recent_posts/?callback=1&custom_fields=image1",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        for(var i = 0; i<4; i++) {
            lookbook_data[i] = data.posts[i].custom_fields.image1[0];      
        }
        continueHere()
     }
 });

 function continueHere() {
      // rest of the code that handles your ajax call
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var lookbook_data = new Array(),
    XHR = $.ajax({
            url: "http://lookbook.king-quinna.nl/api/get_recent_posts/?callback=1&custom_fields=image1",
            dataType: "jsonp"
          });
//anywhere else in your script you can call :
XHR.done(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        lookbook_data[i] = data.posts[i].custom_fields.image1[0];      
    }
    console.log(lookbook_data); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this inside your for loop `console.log(lookbook_data[i]);` inside the success function

Answer (score 0):

use `console.log(lookbook_data);` inside the success function